# Currying: practical implications

Tags: ocaml, currying

My comprehension of the problem comes from [Heilperin's et al. "Concrete Abstraction"](https://www.amazon.it/Concrete-Abstractions-Introduction-Computer-Science/dp/0534952119/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1475508853&sr=8-1&keywords=hailperin+concrete+abstraction). I got that currying is the translation of the evaluation of a function that takes several arguments into evaluating a sequence of functions, each with a single argument. I have clear the semantic differences between the two approaches (can I call them this way?) but I am sure I did not grasp the practical implications behind the two approaches.

Please consider, in Ocaml:

```
# let foo x y = x * y;;
foo : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

and

```
# let foo2 (x, y) = x * y;;
foo2 : int * int -> int = <fun>
```

The results will be the same for the two functions. 
But, practically, what does make the two functions different? Readability? Computational efficiency? My lack of experience fails to give to this problem an adequate reading.

Comment: Don't you mean to compare `let foo x y = x * y;;` and `let foo = fun x -> fun y -> x * y;;`??

Comment: You are correct, thank you for helping me in making it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I would like to stress, that due to compiler optimizations the two functions above will be compiled into the same assembly code. Without the optimizations, the cost of currying would be too high, i.e., an application of a curried function would require allocating an amount of closures equal to the number of arguments.

In practice, curried function is useful, to define partial application. For example, cf.,

```
let double = foo 2
let double2 x = foo2 (2,x)
```

Another implication is that in a curried form, you do not need to allocate temporary tuples for the arguments, like in the example above, the function `double2` will create an unnecessary tuple `(2,x)` every time it is called.

Finally, the curried form, actually simplifies reasoning about functions, as now, instead of having `N` families of `N`-ary functions, we have only unary functions. That allows, to type functions equally, for example, type `'a -> 'b` is applicable to any function, e.g., `int -> int`, `int -> int -> int`, etc. Without currying, we would be required to add a number arguments into the type of a function, with all negative consequences.

Answer (score 1):

With the first implementation you can define, for example

```
let double = foo 2
```

the second implementation can not be partially reused.